# How to make every object property reactive?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

Consider this simplified example:

```
interface Dog {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const puppy: Dog = {
  name: 'Snoop',
  age: 2,
};
```

I want to create a reactive reference for each property in the `puppy` object.

The easiest way is to do this:

```
const puppyName = ref(puppy.name);
const puppyAge = ref(puppy.age);
```

However, this is quite repetitive, so I'm wondering: is there a more generic and type-safe approach to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a builtin function `toRefs`

```
interface Dog {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const puppy: Dog = {
  name: 'Snoop',
  age: 2,
};

import {toRefs} from 'vue'

const puppyRefs = toRefs(puppy)
// const puppyRefs: ToRefs<Dog>

type Pure<T>={[K in keyof T]: T[K]}
type PuppyRefs = Pure<typeof puppyRefs>
// type PuppyRefs = {
//     name: Ref<string>;
//     age: Ref<number>;
// }
```

Comment: This does seem to be same as Behemoth's answer, but using built-in so I'm changing this to be accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reactive()`. https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive

```js
const puppy = reactive({
  name: 'Snoop',
  age: 2,
});

// Accessible like,
console.log(puppy.name);
```

**Typing**

Doc: https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-reactive

`reactive()` implicitly infers the type,

```
const puppy = reactive({
  name: 'Snoop',
  age: 2,
});

// puppy.name is string
```

can explicitly define as,

```
interface Dog {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const puppy: Dog = reactive({
  name: 'Snoop',
  age: 2,
});
```

Comment: That's an interesting option, one downside I see is that as far as typings go, there's no way to tell that `puppy.name` is actually reactive without looking at its origins... Its type is just `string`, not `Ref<string>`. Right?

Comment: Yes, `reactive()` is the recommended way to deal with `Object`. You can directly access the property value without `.value`. Because of that, It doesn't have the type  `Ref<T>` but just `T`.

Comment: Right, I can see that the benefit would be less code and simplicity on the surface. However, I would probably prefer to be more explicit with what is reactive and what isn't. So having `Ref<T>` would probably be preferable for me. For example if I do `const ageNextYear = computed(() => reactivePuppy.age + 1);` - it's not clear why I used `computed`, and someone could refactor it to be just `const ageNextYear = reactivePuppy.age + 1;`, however that would lose reactivity in my understanding...

Comment: Of course, You are right. `reactive()` does the job but it can have these limitations (Mentioned in the doc I shared). It is officially recommended to use `ref()` if you want to overcome those limitations. Nothing wrong.

Comment: The reason, `computed` is used there, is because the `ageNextYear` is not reactive and needs to be recalculated so you can get the latest value every time you access it.

Comment: @MaximMazurok This is the correct solution. reactive() exists exactly for the purpose you asked about, it's idiomatic to Vue. You need refs when you need a reference to a value, e.g reassign it completely. In the example with computed its very usage explains why it's needed, it can be deduced that .age is reactive due to the way how reactivity works in Vue, you don't need to take into account that "someone". You can also combine reactive() with other reactive api to fine-tune the reactivity in an object - computed, ref, markRaw

Comment: @EstusFlask I think you're saying that using reactive() would be the most "vue-way" of doing things. However sometimes I work with junior people and people who never touched front-end before, it's hard enough to deal with the reactivity approach, and if one has to keep in their head what's reactive and what isn't - it might become a mess pretty quickly... I think that having TS guardrails enabled by ref() usage might be a good idea in that case, what do you think?

Comment: @MaximMazurok My humble experience tells the opposite, a junior who's confused with basics can fail in many other ways, only a review can help. `computed(() => a.b)` tells a.b is reactive, not that computed can be removed, needs to be said only once. On the other hand, not every .value is a ref (input.value, saw more than once). Strict lint rules help but not here afaik, but TS can help to force computeds where needed. Non-reactive objects are rare in a comp any way, so it's unnecessary to check what's reactive and what's not, this conforms the prior practice with `this` fields in options api

Comment: Reviews definitely help, unfortunately, in my case I don't have the resources to review all the code. My idea is that if you try to do `a = b + 1` where `b` is a `Ref` - you'll get TS error. So this reminds you that `b` is actually reactive and kinda forces you into using `computed` to keep `b`s reactivity... To be totally honest I haven't used `reactive()` much and so I'm hesitant to introduce it to the product, I might have to play with it on a side first, appreciate your input!

Comment: @MaximMazurok second this, try to consider *everything* being reactive. defineProps()? Reactive. useStore()? Reactive. useFoo()? If it doesn't returns bunch of Refs - Reactive. Functions? If they have reactive arguments when used in reactive(watch/computed) context? Reactive. fetch? Go use reactive wrapper useFetch. A variable I script setup? How dare you use a variable, use Ref. A non-reactive const in script setup? How dare you use non-reactive, go make it computed. Oh, it's a literal? Okay, const literal is fine. No, array literal is not fine, make a reactive. And so on.

Comment: @Dimava that is an interesting way of thinking... However "everything being reactive" starts to sound a bit like AngularJS v1... I think there might be value in thinking about what needs to be reactive and what doesn't, it might help to design more optimal solutions I think...

Comment: @MaximMazurok I'd rather recommend to think about "not losing reactivity" point. Everything may *happen* to be reactive at some point of code, and if your code does not have edge cases where it'd break if the inputs are reactive (`let`, `.bind`/lambdas with `this`, object deconstructing in composables (`useFoo` functions you don't wrap in `computed`) ), then it doesn't really matter if something is reactive or not. An extra `computed` over an already reactive thing won't do anything, an extra `computed` over non-reactive thing won't have a big overhead,

Comment: @MaximMazurok  and if overhead is big you always should `markRaw` your big arrays anyways or if they accidentally become reactive you'll have lags.

Answer (score 1):

Not a Vue expert but how about doing it manually?

```
<script setup  lang="ts">
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue'

function createReactiveRefs<T>(obj: T): { [K in keyof T]: Ref<T[K]> } {
  const reactiveRefs: any = {};

  for (const key in obj) {
    reactiveRefs[key] = ref(obj[key]);
  }

  return reactiveRefs;
}

interface Dog {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const puppy: Dog = {
  name: 'Snoop',
  age: 2,
};

const reactivePuppy = createReactiveRefs(puppy);
</script>

<template>
  {{ reactivePuppy.name.value }}
</template>
```

Comment: I had to disable a few eslint rules: `@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any`, `@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access` and `@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return`, but apart from that seems like a solid answer, it compiles, haven't tested it functionally tho, but accepting it for now, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MaximMazurok there's the same builtin, see my answer